# asp.net core: how AuthenticationHandler and IAuthenticationService are related?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication

i'm trying to understand asp.net core authentication.

I saw that in order to handle a custom schema it's possible to use a class deriving from AuthenticationHandler:

```
services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
            .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);
```

But how this class is related with IAuthenticationService? Does default implementation call handler at some point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you call the function `AddScheme<TOptions,THandler>()` it does the following:

1. Register the handler in IServiceCollection with its concrete type (i.e., in this case, it's equivalent to `services.AddTransient<BasicAuthenticationHandler>()`)
2. Configure the options in IServiceCollection with the Scheme name (i.e., in this case, it's like `services.AddOptions<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>("BasicAuthentication");`)
3. Most importantly, it adds the authentication scheme and handler type in a map within `AuthenticationOptions` so later on, the authentication services know which handler to resolver for each authentication scheme. Check this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d09b931628258850ba0c56d17b3731b72ddf88f5/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationBuilder.cs#L35) if you like digging in the code.

`IAuthenticationService` default implementation `AuthenticationService` when its function `AuthenticateAsync()` is called with a specific scheme it'll resolve the specific handler for that using this map that I explained above. More specifically, it'll use `IAuthenticationHandlerProvider` for this job, the default implementation for it is `AuthenticationHandlerProvider` it has a function `[GetHandlerAsync()][2]` that search a map of (schemes/handlers) and return the appropriate handler matching the scheme.

Of course, this is a much-simplified version of what the authentication handler does behind the scenes with authentication schemes and handlers. But I hope it answers your question ^^

Comment: When this [line](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/16f8b03c2f5b4d3bc82a92ddafc642182e39c1b7/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L62) executes, it ultimately goes [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/16f8b03c2f5b4d3bc82a92ddafc642182e39c1b7/src/Http/Authentication.Abstractions/src/AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.cs#L217) to get the `AuthenticationService`. Where is this service registered? Can you please show me where it's registered in [this](https://github.com/affableashish/blazor-identity-api/blob/main/BlazorServerClient/Program.cs) app?

Comment: I figured this out and documented it [here](https://github.com/affableashish/blazor-identity-api/blob/main/README.md#defaultauthentication).